# How do I display a div over a div then disappear after 10 seconds?

Tags: jquery

I have a SWF file that I play on my website. But before this SWF plays, I want to play another SWF file before it. It's about 10 seconds. So I have a two DIVs: one containing the SWF file that I want to play before, and the other div to contain the SWF I want to present. I believe Jquery can be used to solve my problem. Can anyone help? I tried searching the internet but found no solution. Any help would be gladly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a setTimeout, within a function - call that function when your first SWF  starts playing 
(give it an id, and place that id name in place of 'myFirstSWFid').

This will hide your **#myFirstSWFid** element, 10 seconds after **myFunction()** has been called.

```
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myFirstSWFid').style.display = 'none'
    }, 10000)
};

myFunction();
```